# VSCode cannot launch in ubuntu14.04 with vnc access

Tags: 14.04, vnc, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code installed in Ubuntu 14.04 by using .deb file here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868 . 
The Ubuntu machine is a VM with GNOME desktop and tigervnc-server, I can access it through VNCViewer.

When I run `code .` from terminal, the command just stuck here with no output like this:

```
keith@ubuntu:/home/data$ code .
[space]
```

The same thing happend even when I run `code --version`

```
keith@ubuntu:/home/data$ code --version
[space]
```

I've followed the hack [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3451) to modify `libxcb.so.1` file, unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

This strange problem puzzled me for days, if someone have faced this problem or know how to find out the reason, please tell me, I would be really grateful for that.

Comment: Updates: After 2 years of struggling, finally solved this issue by removing `libachk.so` from `/etc/ld.so.preload`, don't know why, but it's works now

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu 18.04's `tigervnc-server` apparently no longer suffers from this problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3451#issuecomment-437571152).

However, as to your case, you would need to say exactly which steps you followed to see why the `libxcb.so.1` workaround failed...